# fetch first occurrence of numbers from a table column

Tags: mysql

I want to fetch first occurrence of numbers from a table column.

To illustrate:

- For column value '`C 62/3,Industrial Area, Phase 2`', I should get '`62/3`'
- For column value '`B-5 dummy, (dummy)`', I should get '`B-5`'
- For column value '`21 dummy - 2, dummy`' I should get '`21`'.

I tried:

```
select address,SUBSTRING(address, 1, LOCATE(' ', address) - 1) AS str
from items;
```

Comment: Why should `/` be returned in `62/3` but `-` in `-5` not? What is the rule behind?

Comment: i edit my question #Trinimon

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not a MySQL expert but I think you have to use a library like [mysql-udf-regexp](https://github.com/hholzgra/mysql-udf-regexp). Using this you can get the first digit-containing sub string with `REGEXP_SUBSTR`:

```
SELECT 
  address,          
  REGEXP_SUBSTR(address, '[[^:space:]]*[[:digit:]]+[[^:space:]]*', 1, 1) AS str
FROM items;
```

This is untested code but should give you an idea how to proceed. It means that you get any positive number of digits (`[[:digit:]]+`) followed and succeeded by any number of non-white spaces (`[[^:space:]]*`); starting search from first character and return first occurrence (`,1 ,1`).